# What kind of JSON should return from the server in case of error in angular2

Tags: angular

I am making my first angular2 app.

It gets login verification from the server.
It posts username (email) and password to the server and in return it gets the USER OBJECT.

**user.ts**

```
export class User {
    constructor(
    public id: number,
    public email: string,
    public password: string,
    public token: string,
    public firstName: string,
    public lastName: string,
    public lastLogin: number,
    public credits: number,
    public isAdmin: number
    ) { }
}
```

**Success json**

```
 {"id":2,"email":"john.doe@google","password": "", "token":"37ee4a596d443aaf0308c0783bfdcf83","firstName":"John","lastName":"Doe","lastLogin":1486994085,"credits":0,"isAdmin":0}
```

**Failure messages**

```
 {"code":"empty","error":"Password is empty"}
 {"code":"auth-failed","error":"Login information not correct"}
 {"code":"auth-failed","error":"Invalid id\/token, please login again"}
```

Now when went to program my failure messages it got me thinking

My code is this, how will i handle failure in the angular2

```
    return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json() as User)
            .catch(this.handleError);
```

I guess I cannot use the ***response.json() as User*** cause it will crash app in case of error. What is the best practice? Should i change my json format for success also ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should make sure you have the correct HTTP status code set on the response from the server (assuming you control the server). Then, you can set the content of the response to be whatever you want and then handle it however you like based on the status using the catch handler.

```
return this.http.get(url)
        .map(response => response.json() as User)
        .catch(err => /* handle err*/);
```

More info on status codes:

If the server isn't setting the status codes, then you'd have to look at the raw data to see what you're getting (edit: hopefully this isn't the case as your server wouldn't be following the rules).

https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: Which one do you recommend besides status 200. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes **401 status is good** ?

Comment: 401 is the general code used. Note that the rules around 401 say you must provide a WWW-Authenticate header with some basic info, although that probably can be skipped if you're just in a learning/proof of concept exercise. You can see an example of that header here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication

Comment: which status code will you normally use if you are **not** sending 200...?

Comment: For errors originating from what the client sent, I'll send 400 unless there's a more specific one to send. In the failed login case, it would be 401 unless there was some issue logging in not related to the actual authentication (user name and password). One possible scenario: maybe they provided the right information, but some service that writes to an event log isn't working, so a 500 should be sent back as this is a server problem. Here's another site on the status codes that provides some specific examples of when to use what code: http://www.restapitutorial.com/httpstatuscodes.html

Answer (score 1):

Just use `res.json()`

Like this:

```
login(){
        return this.http.get(url)
            .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Then for your function calling this http request like this:

```
    this._yourservice.login().subscribe(
        suc => {
            console.log(suc); // success json, if returned with http response status 200
        },
        err => {
            var res = JSON.parse(err._body);
            console.log(suc); // error json if returned with other http response status
        }
    );
```

Comment: This code doesn't look right. If the error is caught and handled with `catch()`, then the error callback that you pass to `subscribe()` will **never** be called. It's EITHER `catch()` OR `subscribe({err: errorCallback})`, no?

Comment: Yes you are right. I have edited my answer. I never use the catch I only use the success and error callbacks, was from copy/pasting OP's code

Comment: Please let me try this answer. I edit json headers as well as edit angular code. Both. It is big hint. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you return Http status codes other than 200 as part of the server response, then the angular 2 call to `http.get` will throw an exception, directing you `handleError`.